# Python: copy line (tabs)

Tags: python-2.7, copy

My source file is a txt file where I aim to select specific lines based on a few values that are spaced by tabs. My objective is to write these lines to a destination txt file. Every line has the same values of say (a or b), written over about 10 columns (1 value per column).

I have looked at solutions of SO and elsewhere online. I have defined search queries yet they give me error messages. I am just starting out with Python. Thank you for your help.

My code:

```
searchquery1 = \ta\ta\ta   # 3 a's spaced by tab
with open(oldest) as f1:   # source input file
with open('newtest.txt', 'a') as f2:   # output file
    lines = f1.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.endswith(searchquery1):
            f2.writelines(line + "\n")
```

A short example:

source file:

```
A1  a  a  b  b
A2  a  a  a  a
A3  b  b  a  a
...
```

with searchquery1 = 'a  a  a' (values are spaced by a tab)

```
destination file:
A2  a  a  a  a (copy line 2 from source)
```

Comment: The code you wrote definitely does not work. Please provide a short example of your input and wanted output.

Comment: What specific problems are you having with this code?  Are they dependent on the text file, which you have neglected to share?